# SQL Server Sorting Multiple Values from different columns and reassign them based on ascending value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that brings the values of 5 different columns.

```
SELECT TOP 1 digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5 FROM myTable
```

The result is "25, 36, 1, 63, 12".

My question is, how do I sort these numbers in Ascending order and reassign them to their respectively Ascending columns?
I.E: digit1 = 1, digit2 = 12, digit3 = 25, digit4 = 36, digit5 = 63.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an UNPIVOT followed by a PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select Item = concat('digit',Row_NUmber() over (Order by Value))
              ,Value
         From  (Select top 1 * from YourTable) A
         UnPivot ( Value for Digits in (digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4,digit5)  ) U
       ) A 
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in (digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4,digit5) ) P
```

Returns

```
digit1  digit2  digit3  digit4  digit5
1       12      25      36      63
```

Comment: @1moreLearner Happy to help  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from (select top 1 digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5 FROM myTable
     ) t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then digit end) as digit1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then digit end) as digit2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then digit end) as digit3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then digit end) as digit4,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then digit end) as digit5
      from (select v.digit, row_number() over (order by v.digit) as seqnum
            from (values (digit1), (digit2), (digit3), (digit4), (digit5)
                 ) v(digit)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your solution also works. Unfortunately, I don't have a way to up vote your answer. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the results by multiple values, you can use the following syntax.

```
SELECT TOP 1 digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5
```

If the values need manipulation, you may need to create a UDF/CTE or inline expression to determine the 'value' of the columns to order them. Without a full working example (A SQLFiddle would be helpful), it is difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE should allow this to be simplified to something like this. I am assuming that you need this for multiple rows, but simplifying it to a single row is easier than expanding a solution to multiple rows

```
WITH MyData as (
SELECT ID, digit1 as Digit FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, digit2 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, digit3 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, digit4 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, digit5 FROM myTable
)
SELECT ID, Digit
FROM MyData
ORDER BY ID, Digit
```

Your data is now in order. A simple PIVOT will give you the output you are looking for.